# Jquery Infinite Scroll ( IAS ) disable cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, scroll, ias

I am using jQuery + IAS to make infinite scroll, the problem is that i do not want cache disabled when making these requests.

Basically this is the URL is accesses  to get the next page : http://example.com/flink-link?page=3&ccAC=1&_=1473840893821, I need the _=1473840893821 removed.

I have checked their documentation but found nothing, also i tried adding cache: true but it does not work.

Here is my trigger:

```js
        var ias = jQuery.ias({
          container:  '.movie_w',
          item:       '.movie',
          pagination: '#pagination',
          next:       '.next',
          cache: true,
          negativeMargin: 600
        });

    ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension({
        src: domain_root_url+'/media/themes/v/images/load2.gif',
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 'cache: true' to the ajax call (JQuery.ajax({})), not in your ias config's variable.
I had the same issue, and that work to me.